# Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 48 bytes riverpod provider issue

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

when I use provider inside another provider as DI that uses provider the app stops working and printing in the console

> E/DartVM  (16967): Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 669296
> bytes.

my code

```
final client = Provider.autoDispose(
(ref) => dio.Dio()
    ..interceptors.add(RequestsInspectorInterceptor())
    ..options.headers = {
       'Content-Lang': ref.read(getLanguageUseCase),
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      //TODO CHANGE THIS FROM LOCAL
      'country_id': 'countryId',
    },
);
final dioHelper =
    Provider.autoDispose((ref) => DioHelper(dio: ref.read(client)));
```

if I commented this line the app works if not the app will stop working and will seem like hang up

> 'Content-Lang': ref.read(getLanguageUseCase),

Comment: what does `getLanguageUseCase` provider look like?

Comment: Probably the mistake is to use `ref.read` instead of `ref.watch`.

Comment: "getLanguageUseCase" 
looks like that
`final getLanguageUseCase = Provider.autoDispose(
    (ref) => GetLanguageUseCase(ref.read(onBoardingRepository)));`

Comment: why are you using `ref.read`?

Comment: because there is nothing to listen.